# How to change size of varchar2 column of an Oracle database in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I have a simple need to increase the size of a VARCHAR2 column in an Oracle DB from VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) to VARCHAR2(35 CHAR).

The database is used by an existing application with production data though I will start with DEV first (of course).

Comment: You are not providing enough context for anyone to be able to help you with an answer. First question would be "Are you already using Liquibase?". If so, then easy. Just add a changeset with an alter table change. If not, the answer is more complex, and requires more questions. Do you want to start using Liquibase on a regular basis, or is this just a one-off? If you want to start using it on a regular basis, then I would suggest reading the Liquibase docs for how to get started with Liquibase in an existing database.

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve and apologies for my massive assumptions. I am working on a product that already uses Liquibase, the structure and database are in place. I do simply wish to add a changeset to alter a varchar2 column to change its size. The DDL I would run myself would be `ALTER TABLE PCF_PROGRAMME MODIFY (CODE varchar2(35 char));`. How do I achieve this in Liquibase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the Liquibase refactoring "modifyDataType", which is documented here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html

Here is an example:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="modifyDataType-example">
    <modifyDataType 
            columnName="CODE"
            newDataType="varchar2(35 char)"
            tableName="PCF_PROGRAMME"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: what about the rollback section for it (as Liquibase doesn't provide auto-rollback for such change)? Do you know how to handle the case when, at the time of rollback, there will already be data long enough to not fit in the previous field length without modification? In Oracle, for example ALTER TABLE...MODIFY statement seems to throw exception if that happens.

Comment: Yeah, there is no way to roll that back unless you are willing to lose data (or figure out some way to make the data fit). You can't fit 2 gallons of milk in a 1 gallon bucket (unless you dehydrate it).
If you are willing to lose data, you could code the rollback in two steps - first drop all the data that is too big to fit, then resize the column to be smaller.